# How does fungi infection look on Brazilian nuts?

Tags: nuts, mold

I have recently read that Brazilian nuts can be attacked by Aspergillus fungi producing mycotoxins, for example aflatoxins. Does anyone know or saw what infected nuts look like? There are a lot of white coats on nuts I use to buy - should I worry these can be infected?

Few photos with examples:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Mold would be fuzzy. That looks more like physical damage to the nut, but it's extremely difficult to see texture in a photo. Try cracking it with a nutcracker or some way other than cutting it, so you get a rough surface. Compare the broken surface to the areas you're worried might be mold.

Comment: They just look dry & old. Seen better days. They're physically damaged but so long ago the surface oils have evaporated off. I wouldn't worry about mould, i'd just taste one & if it tastes as old as it looks, bin the lot.